# Can we save client SMS responses in AWS Pinpoint's 2-way SMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-js, aws-pinpoint

I know that Amazon Pinpoint enables 2-way SMS, but I was wondering whether it was possible to save the message that the client sends. I'm finding myself going down the AWS rabbit-hole a bit, but I was wondering if anyone has any recommendations as to what AWS services could hold onto response data.

Just to clarify, I understand that Pinpoint allows us to return automated messages when the client passes a keyword. I am also aware that we can create user segments to save user attributes, I am moreso inquiring whether there is a way to **stream user responses** (that are not keywords) to another service or topic. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

An overview of Amazon Pinpoint two-way messaging can be summarized as per the above sample architecture.

You can capture the incoming messages from your users using the SNS topic you would have created when activating Pinpoint two-way messaging ***i.e When your users reply to your SMS message using the long code number, Amazon Pinpoint sends a JSON payload to the Amazon SNS topic that you designated. As a developer you handle these incoming messages by adding subscriptions to this SNS topic. The supported subscriptions include SQS, Lambda, email, HTTPS endpoint or SMS.***

A sample JSON payload that your SNS topic subscriptions would receive would resemble the following :

```
{
  "originationNumber":"+27155550000",
  "destinationNumber":"+2722255511111",
  "messageKeyword":"START",
  "messageBody":"Hello World from Amazon Pinpoint",
  "inboundMessageId":"cae173d2-66b9-564c-8309-66b9",
  "previousPublishedMessageId":"wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY"
}
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! It was exactly what I needed! :)

Comment: Is it possible in any way to attach custom data (Key-Value) to the message that I am sending and get that custom data in the JSON payload when the receiver replies back to the message?